# How to create draw view that support both handwritten text and type text on same page similar to IOS Notes App

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I have created drawView, where user can draw image using finger and Apple Pencil. What I want is to add direct support to typed text like apple notes.

right now, I have both drawView and editerView on two different controller.

For editerView I am using `TextView` and For drawView I am using `UIBezierPath`.

my question is how can combine both functionality in single View ?